# changing the pitch of a music with the web audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In audacity, there's an option to change  the pitch of a music and I want to get that effect with the web audio API but I can't find anything about it, is it possible?

Comment: by height, do you mean volume? there is a gain node you can use to increase volume.

Comment: I meant the pitch, audacity was in french for me so I just translated it directly, my bad

Comment: Ah, no problem. Pitch-shifting is doable, I have not tried this solution, but it could give you some input (no pun): https://github.com/mmckegg/soundbank-pitch-shift

Comment: how do you install it, do I just call index.js in a script tag?

Comment: I've tried that, and it does work, there's a problem with require not being defined